# How to obtain a suitability map by combining an exclusion map and weighted overlay map

Tags: raster, arcmap, raster-calculator, weighted-overlay, suitability-analysis

I currently have 2 map outputs
(1) A classified map (weighted factors)
(2) An exclusion map

I intend to obtain a suitability map by combining the map 2 (the exclusion map) with map 1 (the weighted overlay map). The non-suitable area will be grey for example, and the suitable areas will retain the classification colors from the weighted raster map.

I'm unsure of the right expression to use in the raster calculator.

The first attached image is a representation of the process I'm looking to replicate and
image 2 is an example of the expected result.

[image: overlaying process]
[image]

Ref: https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/15/1/312

Comment: The tool you want is Con https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000 but you must have a spatial analyst license.

Comment: Yes Yess.. I got the results with the Con tool. I'm unsure how to mark this as helpful but it did help me.
Thank you :)